# How to make a generic function that adapts to the model?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am developing a CNN network with Keras

I have a function that I defined where I call `preprocess_input` function of Keras models (VGG16, VGG19,...) [here](https://keras.io/applications/)

So I am doing something like

```
preprocess_input (inputs)
```

However, I want to test several models, resulting in different `preprocess_input` in my function. How can I do to say in my homemade function that I want to use the `preprocess_input` corresponding to the model I am testing ?

I thought about giving the name of my model as a parameter of my function but then, I don't know how to transform this string into a way that allows to call

```
modelThatIwant.preprocess_input(...)
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You can just pass a function as a parameter for the function that trains and evaluates a model. This is a standard thing in python to do.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Sth like `myfct (..., fct)` : ... fct(inputs) where fct is `modelThatIwant.preprocess_input(...)` ?

Comment: Yes, as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the answer is quite easy : you just need to add an argument `fct` in the homemade function you created and then, pass the adequate `preprocessing_inputs` corresponding to the model you want to train... Thanks to @Matias Valdenegro